Django Wagtail, React Native and 3rd Party Signup and Signin
I'm working on a marketplace platform.
My sellers have a web portal to manage their stores.
My buyers have a react native mobile application to access the platform.
My server is running on django wagtail.
I am using django allauth and I'm able to login to my django server from my mobile application. Using username and password and it creates a jwt which my app uses to consume my django api's.
However I would like for my mobile users and web portal users to signup using Google and Facebook providers.
Using the following two links documentation and doc. I have sort of an idea of the flow. However I'm not clear how to use it with firebase as the examples is directly to the 3rd party provider of github.
Based on my research I keep coming across Firebase, how will it play nice with django allauth social?
And will my web portal and mobile app need different integration methods?
I came across this post but the answer doesn't seem complete because if Django doesn't have anything to do with this flow how will it know a user is authorised to consume my API's?

If you're already using allauth, any reason you're not using the allauth social login integration?

That would work for people on the web portal as I understand it? Or are you suggesting when the user on the react native mobile app select Google/ Facebook I open a web frame on my application?
